# How to append data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a `like` function for the recipe so that when the user clicks on "like" button it'll generate something like this on Firebase:

```
users: 
   Key:
      like:
         recipe
            0: recipeKey,
            1: recipeKey
      about: aboutUser
      email: userEmail
      name: userName
      imgURL: userImageURL
      phone: userPhoneNumber
      zipcode: userZipcode
```

I'm using this code to make it happened:

```
this.db.object("users/" + key + "/like/").update({
    recipe
 });
```

Where "recipe" contains the liked "recipeKey". It generates something like this:

```
users: 
  Key:
      like:
         recipe: recipeKey
      about: aboutUser
      email: userEmail
      name: userName
      imgURL: userImageURL
      phone: userPhoneNumber
      zipcode: userZipcode
```

The problem is it doesn't append the new `recipeKey`. It always overwrites the previous `recipeKey` with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `set` function instead of `update`, something like ;

```
function addNewRecipeKey(newRecipeKey, key){
    var recipe = [];
    recipeRef=firebase.database().ref("users/" + key + "/like/recipe");
    recipeRef.once('value', snap=>{
      if (snap.exists()) recipe = snap.val();
       recipe.push(newRecipeKey); // newRecipe that you want to add into.
       recipeRef.set(recipe);
    })
}
```

Comment: recipeKey will come from the recipe table. This code will generate a new random recipeKey and put it inside recipeRef

Comment: No, that's why we created a new empty array. When you send to this function a new recipeKey (assume wrap above into a function, and sent this new recipeKey to this function from your table, every time will increase new reciper key as you showed above `0:recipeKey1,1:recipeKey2,2:recipeKey3...`

Comment: Can't solved the issue. Your solution pushes more than hundreds of data. Don't know why!!

Comment: :) because listening this path with `.on`, (due to your usage I thought this will be better.) Just change it with `.once`  (This will not listen the path) at this line `recipeRef.on('value', snap=>{`

Comment: I've tried with `.once` but the same thing about with twice amount.

Comment: You meant one recipekey recording twice. ? Like: `0:recipekey1,1:recipekey1` ?

Comment: Yes, Same data repeat like hundreds of them

Comment: Please add your full code how you fire the function

Comment: My function looks like this:- `likeRecipe(recipeId) {
    var recipe = [];
    recipeRef=firebase.database().ref('users/" + key + "/like/recipe");
    recipeRef.once('value', snap=>{
       recipe = snap.val();
       recipe.push(recipeId);
       recipeRef.set(recipe);
    })
  }`

Comment: Not the function. How you fire.  From which keylist. I think problem comes from out of function.  Or please add full code.

Comment: I simply call this function by:- `likeRecipe(recipeId) {
    this.angLike.likeRecipe(recipeId);
  }` where angFire is the likeProvider

Comment: Add a console.log(just begining of func). You will see how many  time calls your function from outside.

Comment: I added `console.log()` to check if the function properly passes the `recipeId` and it did print the correct recipe Key for one time.

Comment: At above code one thing is missing which is `key` at path. Hope you also sending a key value to this function.

Comment: Yes I'm sending the recipeKey

Comment: No not this. There is also key value: `ref('users/" + key + "/like/recipe");`

Comment: Yes I'm sending the correct Key, That's why it added the recipeKeys in the user details

Comment: At above you typed your function. There `key` at `ref('users/" + key + "/like/recipe");`  is not defined any where or passed into functions. That's i mean

Comment: Yes, That's not the Key

Comment: So is this the user own key ?  If so, then you need to send `this.user.uid` to function as key.

Comment: Try to correct syntax error at the code: `ref("` instead of `ref('`

Comment: Console.log snap.val() , what you see

Comment: In case not exist, i just edit the code. Please correct as it is

Comment: Hey @AnkurBiswas Did you fix the issue. In case I have an advice more

Comment: That issue hasn't been solved so I've change the structure of my DB

Comment: Ok, well, I just will suggest you retrieve data when you snapshot, use Object.values(snap.val()) (in order to get only values in an array format. (But before console.log of the data snap.val();) I solved the issue like that.